# libc++ Error in instantiation of exception specification for vector and string compiling simple code

Tags: c++11, clang, libc++

I get errors when compiling this simple code and if I remove the noexcept I don't get the error:

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
class Foo
{
public:

protected:
   Foo(Foo&&) noexcept = default;
   Foo& operator=(Foo&&) noexcept = default;

   Foo()
   {
   }

private:

   std::vector<std::string> vectorFoo_;
};
```

This is the errors I get, I understand it is in the instantiation of the exception specification, but I doubt the std::string is not nothrow move constructible,.. the first error make me think there is a bug.

> In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:4:
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:575:67: error: no member named
>   'value' in
>   'std::__1::is_nothrow_move_constructible, std::__1::allocator > > >'
>           *NOEXCEPT*(is_nothrow_move_constructible::value);
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:4:
>   In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:264:
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config:325:34: note: expanded from
>   macro '*NOEXCEPT*'
>   define *NOEXCEPT*(x) noexcept(x)
>                                    ^ In file included from /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:29:29:
>   note: in instantiation of exception specification for 'vector'
>   requested here    std::vector vectorFoo_;
>                               ^ In file included from /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:4:
>   In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:265: In file
>   included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__bit_reference:15: In file
>   included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/algorithm:624:
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/type_traits:2676:53: note: in
>   instantiation of template class
>   'std::__1::add_rvalue_reference, std::__1::allocator > > >'
>   requested here
>       : public is_nothrow_constructible<_Tp, typename add_rvalue_reference<*Tp>::type>
>                                                       ^ In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:4:
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:575:20: note: in instantiation of
>   template class
>   'std::*_1::is_nothrow_move_constructible, std::__1::allocator > > >'
>   requested here
>           *NOEXCEPT*(is_nothrow_move_constructible::value);
>                      ^ In file included from /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:4:
>   In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:264:
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config:325:34: note: expanded from
>   macro '*NOEXCEPT*'
>   define *NOEXCEPT*(x) noexcept(x)
>                                    ^ In file included from /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:29:29:
>   note: in instantiation of exception specification for 'vector'
>   requested here    std::vector vectorFoo_;
>                               ^ In file included from /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:4:
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:582:58: error: no member named
>   'value' in
>   'std::__1::is_nothrow_move_assignable, std::__1::allocator > > >'
>                is_nothrow_move_assignable::value);
>                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:4:
>   In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:264:
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config:325:34: note: expanded from
>   macro '*NOEXCEPT*'
>   define *NOEXCEPT*(x) noexcept(x)
>                                    ^ In file included from /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:29:29:
>   note: in instantiation of exception specification for 'operator='
>   requested here    std::vector vectorFoo_;
>                               ^ In file included from /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:4:
>   In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:265: In file
>   included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__bit_reference:15: In file
>   included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/algorithm:624:
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/type_traits:2760:45: note: in
>   instantiation of template class
>   'std::__1::add_lvalue_reference, std::__1::allocator > > >'
>   requested here
>       : public is_nothrow_assignableTp>::type,
>                                               ^ In file included from /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:4:
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:582:14: note: in instantiation of
>   template class
>   'std::_1::is_nothrow_move_assignable, std::__1::allocator > > >'
>   requested here
>                is_nothrow_move_assignable::value);
>                ^ In file included from /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:4:
>   In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:264:
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config:325:34: note: expanded from
>   macro '*NOEXCEPT*'
>   define *NOEXCEPT*(x) noexcept(x)
>                                    ^ In file included from /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:29:29:
>   note: in instantiation of exception specification for 'operator='
>   requested here    std::vector vectorFoo_;
>                               ^ In file included from /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:4:
>   In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:265: In file
>   included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__bit_reference:15: In file
>   included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/algorithm:624:
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/type_traits:2676:53: note: in
>   instantiation of template class
>   'std::__1::add_rvalue_reference, std::__1::allocator > > >'
>   requested here
>       : public is_nothrow_constructible<_Tp, typename add_rvalue_reference<*Tp>::type>
>                                                       ^ In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:4:
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:575:20: note: in instantiation of
>   template class
>   'std::*_1::is_nothrow_move_constructible, std::__1::allocator > > >'
>   requested here
>           *NOEXCEPT*(is_nothrow_move_constructible::value);
>                      ^ In file included from /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:4:
>   In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:264:
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config:325:34: note: expanded from
>   macro '*NOEXCEPT*'
>   define *NOEXCEPT*(x) noexcept(x)
>                                    ^ In file included from /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.cpp:1:
>   /Users/Mani/Development/Projects/flowOfLife/Graphics/Graphics/TestCompileError.h:29:29:
>   note: in instantiation of exception specification for 'vector'
>   requested here    std::vector vectorFoo_;

My compiler is clang from the top of tree.
What am-I doing wrong?

Thanks

**Update**
[The error on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab2fb522c4982c72). It seam that if I don't specify libc++ and instead use stdlibc++ it compiles. It is starting to look alot like a bug in libc++.

Comment: Of course this works: `Bar& operator=(Bar&& other) noexcept { name = std::move(other.name); return *this; }`...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific bug in the current development version of a program, and already (almost) fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is fine. (and, interestingly enough, so is libc++)

This turns out to be a bug in clang; in fact, recent versions of clang crash when attempting to compile this code.

A patch fixing this in clang is currently being tested and will be part of the 3.4 release.
If you can't wait that long, then you should be able to get a fixed version of clang "really soon now" if you are willing to build it from source.

Thanks to Alp from Nuanti for tracking down the clang bug.

Comment: Thanks alot. I update and build Clang every week, so i'll get it when it will be submitted. Thanks

Comment: Upgrade to XCode 5.0.2 (and so clang) fixed this error for me.

Answer (score 3):

My first assumption was, this might be because the move-assignment operator for `std::string` isn't noexcept (<strike>need to check</strike> see below).

At least, clang and gcc seem to like this better:

```
Bar& operator = (Bar&&) 
     noexcept(
         noexcept(std::declval<std::string>() = std::string())
     ) = default;
```

Now, on Foo clang and gcc don't quite agree, but here's **[Clang live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/896bf2e95875f3a5)**

### Plot twist

More food for thought: The standard appears to explicitely specify the assignment operator (as well as move constructor) for std::string as `noexcept`: **§ 21.4.2**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/lmjq3dX.png]

Comment: I realize this now doesn't answer the question. I'm inclined to leave the info up while I mull this over. I will remove it once a better answer exists.

Comment: Actually I mannaged to reproduce the error on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab2fb522c4982c72) it looks like the enabling libc++ instead of stdlibc++ make the code to break. I guess I should report this as a bug in libc++?